# How do you connect TortoiseSVN on a remote PC to SVN on a hosted server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've installed SVN on a Windows 2008 server hosted by an outfit similar to GoDaddy.  I've installed TortoiseSVN on my local WinXP Pro PC.  How do I connect TortoiseSVN from my local PC to SVN on the hosted server?  I know the IP address of the hosting server, but I don't know how to make a URL out of it.  When I set up SVN and started it as a service, I set the SVN repository to c:\SVN.  My local machine has a bunch of files in d:\TestProject that I'd like to import into SVN.  Initiating the IMPORT command from TortoiseSVN, I tried identifying the SVN repository as \123.123.12.12\c$\svn_repository (note that 123.123.12.12 is a placeholder for the IP address), but that came up with an error telling me "Unrecognized URL scheme"

I've read the manuals, help docs, ... but they are written for a more conversant IT type, or Apache, or something other than what I'm looking for help with.  I'm a programmer for 20+ years, but not a system admin, and I work with a couple other remote programmers - no network admin to consult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

svn://123.123.12.12/ might work.  Actually after the last / there may be some extra path information required based on how your SVN server is configured. I am assuming that You are using svnserve as the server on Windows.

Some of the typical URL schemes for SVN repositories are:

- file:// (if the repository is lying in local file system and no server is being run)
- svn:// (if the server is running through svnserve server)
- http:// (if apache web server is serving your svn repository using WebDAV)

Comment: Shailesh, it looks like your answer is getting me closer, but when I try to connect with svn:///123.123.12.12/ or svn:///123.123.12.12/c$/svn_repository/ or svn:///123.123.12.12/c$/ I get a a pop-up dialog titled "TestProject - Import - TortoiseSVN Failed" and an error description: "Can't connect to host: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".  I'm running svnserver as a Windows service open on port 3690 and the repository in c:\svn_repository.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, using netstat -a command I see that the hosting server is indeed listening on port 3690.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the setup that's making trouble, for Windows, I am very happy with [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/), a free SVN server / wrapper / GUI for SVN. It has graphical configuration and registers with the firewall automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the svn server daemon running, you can connect directly using the svn:// protocol as long as the server has the proper port open (3690 by default). However, communications over the svn protocol are not encrypted.

Another option which is pretty popular is setting up an Apache web server with mod_svn, which allows you to expose your svn repository as a WebDAV resource. You can also secure it by pushing everything over HTTPS and using basic authentication.